# Some sort of to-do list with RxJS

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactivex

I'm currently using RxJS in an angular project. In this project, I have a list that should act as a to-do list :

1. In the beginning, the list is filled with 5 items.
2. The user can remove an element.
3. When an element is removed, a new element is fetched.
4. When the list is empty, new elements are fetched.

I managed to do so using 3 observables and 1 state:

```js
// api.fetchElement -> ({ count: number, exclude: string[] }) => Observable<Element[]>
// removedElements$ -> Subject<string>

let elements = []

const initialElements$ = api.fetchElement({ count: 5 })

// removedElementId$ is a subject of string
// in which element ids are produced.
const reloadedElements$ = removedElementId$.pipe(
    // My API is eventualy consistent, so I need to exclude the removed items
    // for a short period.
    mergeMap(id => api.fetchElement({ count: 5, exclude: [ id ] })
)

const reloadedElementsWhenEmptyList$ = interval(3000).pipe(
    filter(() => elements.length < 5),
    mergeMap(() => api.fetchElement({ count: 5 - elements.length, exclude: elements.map(e => e.id) })
)

initialElements$.subscribe({
    next: newElements => elements = newElements
})

reloadedElements$.subscribe({
    next: newElements => elements = newElements
})

reloadedElementsWhenEmptyList$.subscribe({
    next: newElements => elements = newElements
})
```

The current implementation works, but I'm wondering if there is a way to do the same behaviour but without having to use the final state `elements` in the observable operators?

I've searched for operators in the RxJS docs, but I failed to find any operators or combinations of operators that satisfy my needs.

Comment: How element list will be empty when upon every item removal you are calling API `getElement` to fill element list?

Comment: When the API has no more elements to process, it will return an empty list.

Comment: At reload time itself it will return empty elements if there is no elements. Then why separate for empty$

Comment: I want to reload every time the user removes an item because they can be removed fast. The interval of 3000ms is too large for reloading after the user removed something. 

If I use a shorter time (500ms) for the interval and remove the reloadedElements$ then, when the list will be empty and the API will have no elements left, there will be too many calls.

Comment: I've forgot to mention that elements are not added by the user himself. Those elements are pushed by an external system which can stop pushing items for some interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your settup is a bit bizarre and I can't help but wonder if there's a better way to structure this. Sadly, there's just not enough here to know.

Either way, you can rid yourself of the global state `elements` by creating an observable that emits the most recent `elements` array when subscribed. In this example implementation I've called it `elements$`

```ts
const initialElements$ = api.fetchElement({ count: 5 });

// removedElementId$ is a subject of string
// in which element ids are produced.
const reloadedElements$ = removedElementId$.pipe(
    // My API is eventualy consistent, so I need to exclude the removed items
    // for a short period.
    mergeMap(id => api.fetchElement({ 
      count: 5, 
      exclude: [ id ] 
    }))
);

const reloadedElementsWhenEmptyList$ = interval(3000).pipe(
    switchMap(_ => elements$),
    filter(elements => elements.length < 5),
    mergeMap(elements => api.fetchElement({ 
      count: 5 - elements.length, 
      exclude: elements.map(e => e.id) 
    }))
);

const elements$ = merge(
  initialElements$,
  reloadedElements$,
  reloadedElementsWhenEmptyList$
).pipe(
  startWith([]),
  shareReplay(1)
);
```

You'll notice that when I needed access to your old elements array, I just subscribed to `elements$`.

If you're using TypeScript, it might take some extra work to make sure your types align here. Again, there's not enough info in your example to do this as writ, but I'll leave that exercise to you.